# C++ Server/Client echo strange characters appended to the end for certain input

Tags: c++, tcp, echo

For my echo server/client, when my client talks to my server there is always some weird extra characters at the end of the server echo.

Client (Sending):

```
string input;
while(srnet>0&&start){
cout<<"[Enter to Send]..."<<endl;
 getline(cin,input);
 if(!strcmp(input.c_str(),"quit")) break; else
        srnet=send(conn, input.c_str(),input.length(), 0 );  
}
```

Client (Receiving)

```
while(rnet>0&&start){
char* recvbuf=new char[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
rnet = recv(conn, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

    if (rnet > 0) printf("[RECR %s] %s\n", ip.c_str(),recvbuf);  
    delete recvbuf;
    }
```

Server:

```
rnet = recv(conn, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (rnet > 0) {           
        srnet=send(conn, recvbuf, rnet, 0 );
        if ( srnet== SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[COMM] send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(conn);                
            break;
        }
```

Output:

```
dadada
[Enter to Send]...
[RECR localhost:4666] dadadap
fdsfdfd
[Enter to Send]...
[RECR localhost:4666] fdsfdfd
asdsa
[Enter to Send]...
[RECR localhost:4666] asdsap
asdsa
[Enter to Send]...
[RECR localhost:4666] asdsap
aaa
[Enter to Send]...
[RECR localhost:4666] aaa
asdsa
[Enter to Send]...
[RECR localhost:4666] asdsap
```

Note the extra p was always attached to the input "asdsa" every time. While the other input like "aaa" was fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you extract and show string from `recvbuf`?

Comment: @MM. Apologies for not including that. Added! Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in client side you didn't clip the entry by `\0` before printing it by `printf`. Try this:

```
char recvbuf [DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

while(rnet>0 && start) {

    rnet = recv(conn, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

    if (rnet > 0 && rnet < DEFAULT_BUFLEN-1)
    {
       recvbuf[rnet] = '\0';
       printf("[RECR %s] %s\n", ip.c_str(), recvbuf);  
    }
}
```

I assumed the returned value of `recv` is the length of received buffer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Funny I tried that before but did not work guess I got the rnet wrong as rnet -1 how dumb! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, and better if you aren't confident about having excess buffer space:

```
printf("[RECR %s] %.*s\n", ip.c_str(), rnet, recvbuf);
```